# Keep objects as a grouped based on duplicate value in array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops, object

This is the input array of object:

```
var array = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'A',
    family: 'B',
    number: 100,
    category: 'test',
    time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'A',
    family: 'B',
    number: 100,
    category: 'test',
    time: '2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'A',
    family: 'B',
    number: 100,
    category: 'test',
    time: '2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'A',
    family: 'B',
    number: 100,
    category: 'test',
    time: '2018-03-02T10:36:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'A',
    family: 'C',
    number: 250,
    category: 'other',
    time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'A',
    family: 'C',
    number: 250,
    category: 'other',
    time: '2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z'
  }
]
```

I want to group it like this as output:

```
var output = [
  [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'A',
      family: 'B',
      number: 100,
      category: 'test',
      time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'A',
      family: 'B',
      number: 100,
      category: 'test',
      time: '2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'A',
      family: 'B',
      number: 100,
      category: 'test',
      time: '2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'A',
      family: 'B',
      number: 100,
      category: 'test',
      time: '2018-03-02T10:36:00.000Z'
    }
  ],
  [{
      id: 5,
      name: 'A',
      family: 'C',
      number: 250,
      category: 'other',
      time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z'
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: 'A',
      family: 'C',
      number: 250,
      category: 'other',
      time: '2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z'
    }
  ]
]
```

As you can see, only `id and time`, are unique, and I want to group it based on duplicates`name, family, number and category`, So all objects which have the same value for `name, family, number and category` should have a separate array.

I have tried a lot of things, I used two nested for loop, I used map, I sued Filter, ... I tried all I could think of, but I was not able to do it!

If anyone can help one this, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Show us any code because now this question sounds like "do it for me".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and collect all items of the same group in an array.

Later get only the values of the map as result.

This is only for one one group `category`.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, name: 'A', family: 'B', number: 100, category: 'test', time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z' }, { id: 2, name: 'A', family: 'B', number: 100, category: 'test', time: '2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z' }, { id: 3, name: 'A', family: 'B', number: 100, category: 'test', time: '2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z' }, { id: 4, name: 'A', family: 'B', number: 100, category: 'test', time: '2018-03-02T10:36:00.000Z' }, { id: 5, name: 'A', family: 'C', number: 250, category: 'other', time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z' }, { id: 6, name: 'A', family: 'C', number: 250, category: 'other', time: '2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z' }],
    grouped = Array.from(array.reduce((m, o) =>
        m.set(o.category, (m.get(o.category) || []).concat(o)), new Map).values());

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For more than one group, you could take a joined key with the values of the actual object of `name`, `family`, `number` and `category` in a closure for `key`.

Then map new arrays with close times and combine all arrays to single nested arrays. At the end filter by length.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, sourceAccount: "A", targetAccount: "B", amount: 100, category: "eating_out", time: "2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z" }, { id: 2, sourceAccount: "A", targetAccount: "B", amount: 100, category: "eating_out", time: "2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z" }, { id: 3, sourceAccount: "A", targetAccount: "B", amount: 100, category: "eating_out", time: "2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z" }, { id: 4, sourceAccount: "A", targetAccount: "B", amount: 100, category: "eating_out", time: "2018-03-02T10:36:00.000Z" }, { id: 5, sourceAccount: "A", targetAccount: "C", amount: 250, category: "other", time: "2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z" }, { id: 6, sourceAccount: "A", targetAccount: "C", amount: 250, category: "other", time: "2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z" }],
    groupBy = ['name', 'family', 'number', 'category'],
    result = Array
        .from(
            array
                .reduce((m, o) => (k => m.set(k, (m.get(k) || []).concat(o)))(groupBy.map(k => o[k]).join('|')), new Map)
                .values(),
            o => o.sort((a, b) => a.time.localeCompare(b.time))
        )
        .map(g => g.reduce((r, o, i, a) => {
            if (!i || new Date(o.time).getTime() - new Date(a[i - 1].time).getTime() > 60000) {
                r.push([o]);
            } else {
                r[r.length - 1].push(o);
            }
            return r;
        }, []))
        .reduce((r, a) => r.concat(a), [])
        .filter(a => a.length > 1);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, this is exactly what I need, really appreciate it.

Comment: can I compare the time property value at same time here? let's say If I want to group it only if time difference between each object is less then 1 minute, I know how to get the time difference, but using your solution, I'm a bit confuse that where can I apply this?

Comment: do you need the same groups of `['name', 'family', 'number', 'category']`?

Comment: Yea,I want have the same, like name, family, number, category, and the time difference between each consecutive object if it is less than 1 minute. And one thing else is I noticed, if there is another entry in the array, which have no duplicate value in those 4 property, it will grouped as well, I only want those who are duplicate to be grouped.

Comment: the solution to this request is a bit greater, than before, becuase you need a special treatment for every key. in this case, an object with functions for each case would be better and easier to maintain. what do you mean with the last sentence? do you need only entries with at least two elements?

Comment: Correct, atleast two elements, like if we had another entry lets' say with category:'food' , name:'A' , family:'T' number:334, this should not be grouped. About the time, can I used the grouped array and do another reduce on that and compare it from there?

Comment: is the array sorted by time?

Comment: No, it's not sorted, after get the desired output I need to sorted using ascending sort. basically I need to list of all the duplicate object groups, with time difference between each consecutive object if it's less than 1 minute. ordered by time ascending in this format (output[][])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176461/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-emad-dehnavi).

Answer (score 3):

Simply make a map using [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with a combined key of `name, family,number and category`. And than you can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) on that map to get the desired result.

```js
var array =[ { id: 1, name: 'A', family: 'B', number: 100, category: 'test', time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z' }, { id: 2, name: 'A', family: 'B', number: 100, category: 'test', time: '2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z' }, { id: 3, name: 'A', family: 'B', number: 100, category: 'test', time: '2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z' }, { id: 4, name: 'A', family: 'B', number: 100, category: 'test', time: '2018-03-02T10:36:00.000Z' }, { id: 5, name: 'A', family: 'C', number: 250, category: 'other', time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z' }, { id: 6, name: 'A', family: 'C', number: 250, category: 'other', time: '2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z' } ];

var result = Object.values(array.reduce((a,curr)=>{
  const {name, family, number, category} = curr;
  const key = `${name}_${family}_${number}_${category}`;
  (a[key] = a[key] || []).push(curr);
  return a;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Instead of just adding `curr.name+curr.family+curr.number+curr.category` together, I'd put a delimiter of some sort, like a semicolon or something else unlikely to be in the original data, between each item.

Comment: @kshetline thanks for the suggestion. Updated the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Array.reduce()` to get that output:

```js
var array = [ { id: 1,
  name: 'A',
  family: 'B',
  number: 100,
  category: 'test',
  time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z' },
  { id: 2,
  name: 'A',
  family: 'B',
  number: 100,
  category: 'test',
  time: '2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z' },
  { id: 3,
  name: 'A',
  family: 'B',
  number: 100,
  category: 'test',
  time: '2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z' },
  { id: 4,
  name: 'A',
  family: 'B',
  number: 100,
  category: 'test',
  time: '2018-03-02T10:36:00.000Z' },
  { id: 5,
  name: 'A',
  family: 'C',
  number: 250,
  category: 'other',
  time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z' },
  { id: 6,
  name: 'A',
  family: 'C',
  number: 250,
  category: 'other',
  time: '2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z' } 

];

var res = array.reduce((acc, obj)=>{
  var existObj;
  for(var i = 0 ; i < acc.length; i++) {
    let accArray = acc[i];
    if(accArray){
     existObj = accArray.find(({name, family, number, category}) =>  name == obj.name && family == obj.family && number == obj.number && category == obj.category);
     if(existObj) {
        accArray.push(obj);
        return acc;
     }
    }
 }
  acc.push([obj]);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```